# AngularJS Role Based Navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular to build a small web application. I'm trying to set up role based navigation. It seems as if the isAdmin function is not getting called on page load, as I can just see the foo anchor tag.
 
HTML

```
<body ng-controller='AccountController'>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <ul>
          <li><a href='google.com'>foo</a></li>
          <li ng-if="isAdmin()"><a href='google.com'>bar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
```

AccountController

```
var app = angular.module('appControllers', []);

app.controller = angular.controller('AccountController', ['$scope', 
function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.isAdmin = function() {
        return true; //Just as a test to make sure it works
    }
}]);
```

Ideally this will hit a web service that will return the administrator status, but for now I'd like to get this to work.

Thanks for all the help in advance,

Andres

Comment: Refer to - http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/

Comment: You sure that there can't be an error in the JS you didn't show us? :) Are there any JS Errors?

Comment: Sadly, no JS errors, nothing popped in the console.

Comment: @AndresL Are you positive there are no console errors? I would expect at least a type error along the lines of undefined is not a function (Chrome).

Is your isAdmin function declared anywhere else on your scope?

Comment: @Matt, sorry, I haven't shown all the code, just what I thought was pertinent. I declare it in a module, which then defines the function in the question within a controller declaration.

Comment: @AndresL Your code appears to work for the most part for me... see: [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UWJjBf?p=info) . All that I did was change the controller declaration and inject the missing $http. It appears that you only want this item to generate based on your ng-if condition. Am I mis-understanding your question?

Comment: You understood it perfectly. I'm going to copy the code out of that plunkr and paste it in and hope it works. Must've just been a stupid mistake on my part. That happens a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you need to remove braces to make it work. But I usually use custom directive to make it work. Example:

```
<div class="somediv" show-for-role="ROLE_A,ROLE_B"></div>
```

And if your user has some of these roles your can manage it.

```
appModule.directive('manageAccess', ['someState', function (appState) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var user = someState.currentUser;
      scope.$watch(someState.watchCurrentUser, function(n,o){
         if (n === o){
           return;
         }
        hideShow(element,attrs,n);
      });
      hideShow(element,attrs,user);
    }
  }

var hideShow = function(element,attrs,user){
element.hide();
if (user) {
  var role = attrs.showForRole;
  if (role){
    role.split(',').forEach(function(it){
      if (it == user.role){
        element.show();
      }
    })
  }
}};
```

Comment: I have yet to use a custom directive, so this should be an adventure. I'll give it a try tomorrow when I get back into work. I'll post an update then, thanks Artemis

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove extra '()' after 'isAdmin' like that :

```
function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.isAdmin = function() {
        return true; //Just as a test to make sure it works
    }
}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Your welcome. Don't forget to mark the response in the case of someone else get the same issue as you ! Let me know if it works

Comment: I mistyped it, I had already removed the parentheses.. I'll edit the question.